# Magento 2 Error message: Invalid state change requested

Tags: magento2

I've created custom **Rest API** for adding and removing products from cart.

I am able to add and delete products from my cart, but when I log in as a customer, I can't add or delete products from cart.

API throws message: *Invalid state change requested.*

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Yes, this error disappeared when we pass the Authentication Token n headers.

Comment: I have same error and how to pass "Authentication Token" in headers?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145552)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145552)

Comment: But in my case for logged in customers when I pass Authentication Token in headers, this issue gets disappeared.
Am not sure whether this is correct solution for this issue. If it is not, then please suggest us correct solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the custom REST API is throwing **"Error message: Invalid state change requested"** when customer does not pass the **Authentication Token** in headers. Magento 2 doesn't give access to Quote for users without authentication token.

Comment: Good one. +1 for that :)

Comment: @Prabhu M.: I have extended ShippingInformationManagement using preference and facing same error on normal checkout flow with new registered user. Can you plese help me.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /**
>  * Checks if change quote's customer id is allowed for current user.
>  *
>  * @param CartRepositoryInterface $subject
>  * @param Quote $quote
>  * @throws StateException if Guest has customer_id or Customer's customer_id not much with user_id
>  * or unknown user's type
>  * @return void
>  * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
>  */
> ```

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Plugin/AccessChangeQuoteControl.php#L46

Judging by the methods docs there may be issues with the Quote not matching or not allowed.

`Checks if change quote's customer id is allowed for current user.`

...

`StateException if Guest has customer_id or Customer's customer_id not much with user_id or unknown user's type`

Comment: It is checking the below case in AccessChangeQuoteControl.php
**case UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_GUEST:
                $isAllowed = ($quote->getCustomerId() === null);
                break;**
when i echo $quote->getCustomerId(), it returns me null, hence the above case breaks, $isAllowed variable is set to false and returns me **message: Invalid state change requested.**
Why is my $quote->getCustomerId() is null?

Comment: If the context is hitting the `USER_TYPE_GUEST` then the customer hasn't been logged in properly over the API possibly.

Comment: I checked it by creating new customer account too, but still the context is hitting USER_TYPE_GUEST when i try to add product using custom **Rest Api** . 
       $params = array( 
                         'form_key' => $this->_formkey->getFormKey(),
                         'product' => $productId, 
                         'qty'   =>$qty        
                     );  
         $this->_cart->addProduct($product_collection, $params);
         $this->_cart->save();

Comment: Any solution in Magento 2.4.5-p1 this same issue is happening where even few customers is login it ends up hitting USER_TYPE_GUEST not the login one. Any solution for same or idea how to regenerate or debug it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to reauthorize my integration. So I went to `System->Integration->{my integration}` and clicked on the `Reauthorize` button.

I had my integration for the rest API, but I believe the bearer token( `Access Token`) was incorrect, or it was expired.

I left this post, maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following https://github.com/myparcelnl/magento/issues/171#issuecomment-544443956 for a solution to this issue.